# Gmail API send e-mail using other credentials

Tags: php, gmail, gmail-api

```
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
$service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
$email = createMessage("test email");
sendMessage($service,"me",$email);


function createMessage($email) {

  $to ="email@addrress.com";
  $strSubject = 'TEST THREAD123125';
  $strRawMessage = "From: apitest@gmail.com\r\n";
  $strRawMessage .= "To: ".$to." \r\n";
  $strRawMessage .= "Cc:" .  $to  . "\r\n";
  $strRawMessage .= 'Subject: =?utf-8?B?' . base64_encode($strSubject) . "?=\r\n";
  $strRawMessage .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $strRawMessage .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
  $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . "\r\n\r\n";
  $strRawMessage .= "this <b>is a test message!\r\n";
  $mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($strRawMessage), '+/', '-_'), '=');
  $message = new \Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
  $message->setRaw($mime);
  return $message;
}


function sendMessage($service, $userId, $message) {
  try {
    $message = $service->users_messages->send($userId, $message);
    print 'Message with ID: ' . $message->getId() . ' sent.';
    return $message;
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

I am trying to use this function based on the documentation on https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send

Since I used the gmail authentication the default value of $userid is "me". Is there are any possibility to change the value of "me" to another email (the email that I used to on the credentials.json).

Comment: Hi there @Chillax, what do you mean mean by changing the value of `me` to the one you used on the `credentials.json`? Can you please provide more information on this and what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: -@ale13 I created an API using apitest@gmail.com for logging in my main emailadd (main@gmail.com) then Im trying to send an email using the apitest@gmail.com if I changed the "me" on parameters of $userid to apitest@gmail.com it says delegation denied. but when I changed it to "me" it can send email but using main email add which i used to logged

Comment: @ale13 I added the codes that I used to send email

Comment: For which account did you obtain the `credentials.json` for Gmail API? @Chillax

Answer (score 0):

The `delegation denied` error message you are receiving is due to the fact that the other email address you are using for the request is not the authorized one in this situation.

When you obtained the `access token`, you obtained it for `main@gmail.com` but this does not grant access to the other email address mentioned `apitest@gmail.com`.

According to the [Handling authorization requests documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server#handling_authorization_requests):

> When a user loads your application for the first time, they are presented with a dialog to grant permission for your application to access their Gmail account with the requested permission scopes. After this initial authorization, the user is only presented with the permission dialog if your app's client ID changes or the requested scopes have changed.

### Reference

- [Implementing Server-Side Authorization](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server)

Comment: How can Authorizing with stored credentials ? via php ?